# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a function to convert a string to `datetime (101)` format. 
But it gives me an error when I convert this value.

```
2016-03-01 00:00:00.0000000
```

And the error is

```
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

And my function is ..

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[ConvertToDate] 
(
    @Value nVarchar(MAX)
)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    IF (@Value <> NULL OR @Value <> '')
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @dt DATETIME
            SET @dt = CONVERT(DATETIME,@Value,101)
            --SET @dt = CAST(@Value AS DATETIME(101))
            RETURN @dt
        END

        RETURN NULL

END
```

What is the problem?

Comment: **Side note:** `@Value <> NULL`. If you compare anything with `NULL` using <> the result is `NULL`, and not true or false. The correct way is `@Value IS NOT NULL`

Comment: convert in YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss:

Comment: use datetime2 it can hadle more seconds

Comment: @ughai valuable information ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too many zeros in the millisecond part. This works fine

```
DECLARE @Value nVarchar(MAX)='2016-03-01 00:00:00.000'
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,@Value,101)
```

You can try using `LEFT` like this

```
DECLARE @Value nVarchar(MAX)='2016-03-01 00:00:00.000000'
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT(@Value,23),101)
```

Answer (score 3):

It is problem your data. It is not converting. 
Your data should be like this

```
'2016-03-01 00:00:00.0000000'
```

But you can change your data like this

```
'2016-03-01 00:00:00.000'
```

Comment: how can I change that.. is there any way to convert them

Comment: @tarzanbappa if you want to convert then you can use substring like below DECLARE (at)dt VARCHAR(50) ='2016-03-01 00:00:00.0000000'
select  CAST(SUBSTRING((at)dt,1,16) AS datetime)  , but is is not necessary you can directly use datetime2  that is better option

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @dt VARCHAR(50) ='2016-03-01 00:00:00.000000'

select CAST (@dt AS DATETIME2)
```